# Sonarqube skipping some files and showing 0 lines

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Sonarqube skipping some files and showing 0 lines (the files are in the same package)
Sonarqube Community Edition 9.8

[image]

Comment: It looks error is within the file. I removed the contents of the file and just kept package definition and classname, then it shows 2 lines correctly

Answer (score 0):

Java version was not set in maven pom.xml due to which sonarqube was considering java version 5 as default and skipped the files that has features that are available only in the versions 6 or later.

After specificing the correct version in pom.xml, (release for java 9 or later, source and target until java 8), the issue has resolved